# Moving marker cursor on two maps Mapbox

Tags: mapbox

I would like to move a marker cursor at the same position and the same time as the default cursor over a Mapbox map when is moved active map cursor.

It's an application with two divs with a map in every div, but by default only appears one cursor over the active map, see JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6q2mdn3f/

I need to show two cursors, attached image with left map showing an arrow but, how can I do it?

[image]

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>2 Mapes - Mapbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #map,
    #map2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #map2 {
      right: 0px;
    }

    #divider {
      background-color: gray;
      width: 8px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="divider"></div>
    <div id="map2"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    window.onload = function () { mapBoxInit(); }

    window.onresize = function () {
      setWindowSize();
    }

    function setWindowSize() {
      var width = (window.innerWidth - 6) / 2;
      d3.select("#map").style("width", width + "px")
      d3.select("#map2").style("width", width + "px")
    }
    setWindowSize();

    function mapBoxInit() {

      // mapbox access token
      mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYm9lcmljIiwiYSI6IkZEU3BSTjQifQ.XDXwKy2vBdzFEjndnE4N7Q';

      // define the first map
      var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        maxZoom: 14, //13
        minZoom: 4,
        zoom: 12,
        center: [-0.1, 51.51],
        //style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/bright-v8',
        //style: 'topo-raster-tiles.json',
        style: 'https://geoserveis.icgc.cat/contextmaps/icgc.json',
        hash: false
      });

      // Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
      map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

      // define the second map
      var map2 = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map2',
        maxZoom: 14, //13
        minZoom: 4,
        zoom: 11,
        center: [-0.1, 51.51],
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/bright-v8',
        hash: false
      });

      // Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
      map2.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

      // coordination between the two maps
      var disable = false;
      map.on("move", function () {
        if (!disable) {
          var center = map.getCenter();
          var zoom = map.getZoom();
          var pitch = map.getPitch();
          var bearing = map.getBearing();

          disable = true;
          map2.setCenter(center);
          map2.setZoom(zoom);
          map2.setPitch(pitch);
          map2.setBearing(bearing);
          disable = false;
        }
      })

      map2.on("move", function () {
        if (!disable) {
          var center = map2.getCenter();
          var zoom = map2.getZoom();
          var pitch = map2.getPitch();
          var bearing = map2.getBearing();

          disable = true;
          map.setCenter(center);
          map.setZoom(zoom);
          map.setPitch(pitch);
          map.setBearing(bearing);
          disable = false;
        }
      })

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this style (change `url`):

```css
.marker {
    background-image: url('cursor.png');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

`cursor.png` -> [image]

Add this script into `mapBoxInit` (change `anchor`. It is `'top-left'` for the image I use):

```js
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';

var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el, {anchor:'top-left'});

map.on("mousemove", function (e) {
    marker.setLngLat(e.lngLat).addTo(map2);
});

map2.on("mousemove", function (e) {
    marker.setLngLat(e.lngLat).addTo(map);
});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello @kadir. It works perfectly !. I've made a fiddl to share a running example: [https://jsfiddle.net/ToniBCN/a0yhtsxm/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/ToniBCN/a0yhtsxm/6/)  Thanks a lot.